# java unchecked cast

Tags: java, generics, compiler-warnings

I have a comparator class in Java to compare Map entries:

```
public class ScoreComp implements Comparator<Object> {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        Entry<Integer, Double> m1 = null;
        Entry<Integer, Double> m2 = null;

        try {
            m1 = (Map.Entry<Integer, Double>)o1;
            m2 = (Map.Entry<Integer, Double>)o2;
        } catch (ClassCastException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Double x = m1.getValue();
        Double y = m2.getValue();
        if (x < y)
            return -1;
        else if (x == y)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;        
     }

}
```

when I compile this program I get the following:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Double>
            m1 = (Map.Entry<Integer, Double>)o1;
```

I need to sort map entries on the basis of the Double Values.

If I create the following comparator then I get an error in the call to sort function of Arrays (I am getting an entry set from the map and then using the set as an array).

```
public class ScoreComp implements Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Double>>
```

how to implement this scenario.

Comment: What do you mean by using the set as an array ?

Comment: see the comment below stacker's reply

Comment: This has nothing to do with exceptions; I have changed the title and tags accordingly

Comment: even though you updated the question, the link to the question did not change ... lol

Comment: hey the url changed. so how does this work. after i edit the post's title the old url to the question would stop working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stacker has described how to fix the code you've shown. Here's how to fix the code in your comment: First of all, don't use arrays, because arrays don't work with generics (you cannot have an array of a generic type). Instead, you can use a `List` and the `Collections.sort()` method:

```
    List<Map.Entry<Integer, Double>> mList = 
        new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, Double>>(Score.entrySet()); 
    Collections.sort(mList, new ScoreComp());
```

Comment: how i wish i could accept two answers as correct. your answer is good but for my work i would be using skaffman's approach.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you're using this comparator to sort a `TreeMap`, then this isn't going to work.  `TreeMap` comparators are for comparing only the map keys, not the key->value entries. If your comparator needs access to the values, then it will have to look them up in the map itself, e.g.

```
final Map<Integer, Double> map = ....

public class ScoreComp implements Comparator<Integer>  {
   public int compare(Integer key1, Integer key2) {
    Double x = map.getValue();
    Double y = map.getValue();
    if (x < y)
        return -1;
    else if (x == y)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1; 
   }
}
```

---

**edit:** From your comments, I think your best option is to create a class that encapsulates the ID and the value, put those values into a List, and sort that.

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
   int id;
   double value;

   public int compareTo(Item other) {
      return this.value - other.value;
   }
}
```

and then

```
List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
// ... add items here
Collections.sort(list);
```

Since `Item` is itself `Comparable`, you don't need an external `Comparator` (unless you want one).

Comment: what if i need to sort on the basis of values and the values are not unique so that the keys have to be integer and i want to keep the key and the value together, to make my code look easy to understand.

Comment: Are you actually using the Integer values for anything? Who not just put the Doubles into a List, and sort that?

Comment: after i sort the double values i need to be able to identify which double value belongs to which id.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145853/java-treemap-get-values-in-sorted-order

Comment: only thing is i could not find a built in pair data structure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java

Answer (score 2):

What's about rewriting as

```
public class ScoreComp implements Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Double>> {

    public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Double> o1, Map.Entry<Integer, Double> o2) {
        if ( o1.getValue()  < o2.getValue()  ) return -1;
        else if ( o1.getValue() == o2.getValue()  ) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: then i get an error in the call to sort.
`     Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Double>> mSet = Score.entrySet();
     Object[] arr = mSet.toArray();
     Arrays.sort(arr, new ScoreComp());`

Comment: No, this won't work, because the `TreeMap` routines will not pass in the `Map.Entry` values, no matter how hard you try to make it compile

Comment: well the code in my question was compiling with a version 6.5 of netbeans on windows . but it does not compile on netbeans 6.8 on linux. (java is 1.6 on both - strange)